# Unbind delegated event where the jQuery object is stored inside a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to unbind a delegated event on a specific element. Right now, I'm finding the element with jQuery functions and storing it inside a variable.

But since it's in a variable and it was a delegated event, I'm not sure how to unbind its events.

In this example, when I click on a one of the Foo's, its sibling's (Bar) events should be unbound:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <p class="foo">Foo 1</p>
    <p class="bar">Bar 1</p>
</div>

<div>
    <p class="foo">Foo 2</p>
    <p class="bar">Bar 2</p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '.bar', function() {
    alert('Bar');
});

$(document).on('click', '.foo', function() {
    alert('Foo');
    var $sibling = $(this).siblings('.bar');
    // unbind $sibling
});
```

I've tried:

```
$sibling.off();

$sibling.unbind();

$(document).off('click', $sibling);

$(document).unbind('click', $sibling);
```

None of these work.

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pyL2sLfx/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.bar', function() {
```

This doesn't bind an event listener dynamically on each '.bar' element. This binds an event listener on the document, such as when a click occurs, when the event *bubbled up* to the document, if the event target matches `'.bar'`, the listener is called.

Two workarounds

- [with classes](http://jsfiddle.net/orbtf5sh/1/):

  ```
  $(document).on('click', '.bar', function() {
      if( $(this).hasClass('disabled') ) return;
      alert('Bar');
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.foo', function() {
      alert('Foo');
      var $sibling = $(this).siblings('.bar');
      // unbind $sibling
      $sibling.addClass('disabled');
  });
  ```
- [with stopPropagation](http://jsfiddle.net/orbtf5sh/2/):

  ```
  $(document).on('click', '.bar', function() {
      alert('Bar');
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.foo', function() {
      alert('Foo');
      var $sibling = $(this).siblings('.bar');
      // unbind $sibling
      $sibling.on('click', function(event) {
          event.stopPropagation();
      });
  });
  ```

Documentation: [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Here is a [variation of the second workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/orbtf5sh/3/) such as you can call `$sibling.off('click', stopPropagation);` if needed.

Comment: I used stopPropagation(). Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you are binding the event on document, and not on p elements. But you are trying unbind the p elements.

change your original bind to this.

```
$(function () {
    $('.bar').on('click', function() {
        alert('Bar');
    });

    $('.foo').on('click', function() {
        alert('Foo');
        var $sibling = $(this).siblings('.bar');
        $sibling.unbind();
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm binding the events on document because the content is dynamically loaded. This would work with static content.

Comment: try remove '.bar' class of element instend unbind. `$sibling.removeClass('bar')`.